# Using isinstance in modules

Tags: python

I've observed a weird phenomena involving object "AuditResult" that I'm hoping someone can help me understand.  I have a module set up like this:

```
model\
   __init__.py
   common.py  (AuditResult is imported from audit.py into here)
   audit.py   (where AuditResult lives)
   objects.py
   test.py
```

In test.py, if I imported the AuditResult object using `from common import AuditResult`, the following results occur:

```
>>> isinstance(audit_obj, AuditResult)
False
>>> type(audit_obj)
<class 'model.audit.AuditResult'>
>>> AuditResult
<class 'audit.AuditResult'>
```

However, if I use `from model.common import AuditResult`, the code functions as expected.

```
>>> isinstance(audit_obj, AuditResult)
True
>>> type(audit_obj)
<class 'model.audit.AuditResult'>
>>> AuditResult
<class 'model.audit.AuditResult'>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that doing:

```
from common import AuditResult
```

will import the `common` module as a "standalone module" while:

```
from model.common import AuditResult
```

will import it as a submodule of `model`. Python *distinguishes* between the two modules! There is *no relation* between `common` imported in the former way and `common` imported in the latter case. Since the code is executed twice the `AuditResult` are *different* classes hence the `isinstance` *correctly* returns `False` when you mix them.

You can test this doing:

```
import common
from model import common as common2
print(common is common2)
```

you'll see that this prints `False`. And if the modules are different all their contents are different so also:

```
print(common.AuditResult is common2.AuditResult)
```

will print `False`.

Keep in mind that python does **not** use a structural equivalence for types, i.e. it does *not* check if "the classes are essentially the same". `isinstance` just check whether the class associated with an instance `is` *exactly* the class passed as second argument. In your case the *two* `AuditResult` are *different* classes, hence an instance of `audit.AuditResult` is **not** an instance of `model.audit.AuditResult`.

---

In fact this is the only way that I know where a module can be imported twice without messing with the internals of the import mechanism.

---

I advise you to *avoid* the absolute import of the submodule, i.e.:

```
from common import AuditResult
```

If you want to make a relative import use the relative import syntax:

```
from .common import AuditResult
```

Note the `.`(dot). This tells python to import `common` from the current package.

Comment: Correct me if I’m wrong, but I think the ``from common import AuditResult`` way of importing a module within the same package has been removed in python3?

Comment: @JonasWielicki Yes and no. If you add the directory in the pythonpath it *will* work. In python2 *when using the `-m` switch* those imports *could* be interpreted as relative. In python3 *all* imports are absolute *except* when using the explicit syntax.

Comment: Ah ok. But isn’t adding the directory of a package to the pythonpath  bad practice, or is there a reason to do that?

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, I think I understand the issue.  The only thing is when I try to do the relative import I get ```ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package```

Comment: @jsexauer If you want to run a submodule of a package use the `-m` switch. For example `python -m model.common`. (and you should be in the *parent* directory of `model`). Using `python model/common.py` or `cd model; python common.py` the interpreter will *not* recognize the package at all, hence your error. And  yes, adding the package to the pythonpath *is* bad practice.